# Best way to test views in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, bdd

I've been using RSpec for testing my Rails application, but I find that testing views, partials and helpers that it isn't fully optimized for that. Can someone suggest a better approach to testing these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many users will pair RSpec with [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/). Cucumber provides higher level testing and will allow you to test most aspects of your views efficiently.

**Edit:**

A few resources:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/159-more-on-cucumber
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/186-pickle-with-cucumber
- http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book

Answer (score 1):

Helpers are really easy to test with RSpec, but views and partials can be tricky since you really are doing an integration test. For these I use Cucumber since it allows you to describe the behavior in plain english and then use a nice DSL like Capybara to interact with the application. Much bigger learning curve for Cucumber than RSpec (IMHO), but the payoff has big rewards.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. Cucumbers all the way. Also see:

http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book
http://peepcode.com/products/cucumber

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Cucumber is RSpec request specs. The syntax is less natural than Cucumber, but still very readable.